# gsutil with a custom .boto file

Tags: boto, gsutil

I am trying to use gsutil with a custom .boto file, but I cannot get gsutil to look at my custom .boto file.

```
BOTO_CONFIG=/app/.custombotofile gsutil ls
BOTO_PATH=./app/.custombotofile gsutil ls
```

Both of these commands use the default .boto file.

```
gsutil -v
gsutil version: 4.28
```

> Update1:
>
> These commands work on my local machine, but not inside a docker
>   container

Update2:

mhouglum's answer provided a key insite. Using

```
gsutil version -l
```

gives

```
[...]
config path(s): /Users/jhill/.boto /default/path/from/gcloud/.boto
[...]
```

Running

```
gcloud config set pass_credentials_to_gsutil false && gsutil version -l
```

gives

```
[...]
config path(s): /Users/jhill/.boto
[...]
```

I.e. removes the path I did not want. gsutil works in docker container now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debugging steps I'd recommend here include:

1) Make sure you can open and read the file, e.g. run this from your shell:

```
if [[ -r /app/.custombotofile ]]; then echo "readable"; fi
```

2) Run `gsutil version -l` and check if either the boto file is not being loaded, or another boto file is being loaded afterward and overwriting options from the first file (this happens when using a gcloud-packaged installation of gsutil if you've run `gcloud auth login`, as illustrated below):

```
$ BOTO_CONFIG="/home/bob/.anotherboto" gsutil version -l
[...]
using cloud sdk: True
pass cloud sdk credentials to gsutil: True
config path(s): /home/bob/.anotherboto, /home/bob/.config/gcloud/legacy_credentials/bobs.email@gmail.com/.boto
[...]
```

If gcloud is indeed loading another .boto file, you can stop this behavior by running this gcloud command:

```
$ gcloud config set pass_credentials_to_gsutil false
```

Comment: Thanks mate. You made my day with these two commands: gcloud config set pass_credentials_to_gsutil false && gsutil version -l